# 100% CPU usage with libev

Tags: c, libev

I have a tcp server which uses libev as an event loop; for new accepted sockets
i set:

```
 ev_io_init(&conn->io, tcp_conn_on_event_cb, conn->fd, EV_READ | EV_WRITE);
```

when a new connection is comming, my server consumes whole the CPU cycles, i have 100% CPU usage. my program calls all the time the callback **tcp_conn_on_event_cb** with revents set as EV_WRITE

```
static void tcp_conn_on_event_cb(ev_loop_t *loop, ev_io *ev, int revents)
```

when i make

```
strace mybinary
```

i've this:

```
epoll_wait(4, {{EPOLLOUT, {u32=7, u64=4294967303}}}, 64, 59743) = 1
epoll_wait(4, {{EPOLLOUT, {u32=7, u64=4294967303}}}, 64, 59743) = 1
epoll_wait(4, {{EPOLLOUT, {u32=7, u64=4294967303}}}, 64, 59743) = 1
epoll_wait(4, {{EPOLLOUT, {u32=7, u64=4294967303}}}, 64, 59743) = 1
epoll_wait(4, {{EPOLLOUT, {u32=7, u64=4294967303}}}, 64, 59743) = 1
epoll_wait(4, {{EPOLLOUT, {u32=7, u64=4294967303}}}, 64, 59743) = 1
epoll_wait(4, {{EPOLLOUT, {u32=7, u64=4294967303}}}, 64, 59743) = 1
                           ....
```

is there a solution fo this problem please?

Answer (score 4):

I've found a solution, For those who are interested in this question:

when accepting a new socket, do not **call ev_io_init** with **EV_WRITE**, call it only with EV_READ.

```
ev_io_init(&conn->io, tcp_conn_on_event_cb, conn->fd, EV_READ);
```

in the callback, if you have a data to write (to the socket), you can use **ev_feed_fd_event**

```
static void tcp_conn_on_event_cb(ev_loop_t *loop, ev_io *ev, int revents)
{
      ....

    if (revents | EV_WRITE) {
         /* write your data here */
    }

    if (data_is_ready()) {
        ev_feed_fd_event(loop, conn->fd, EV_WRITE | revents);
        return;
    }

    /* do other job */
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me. I was behind timers causing high CPU. But this solved my issue. I was setting both EV_READ and EV_WRITE for new socket.